# Match string in Perl with space or with no-space in it

Tags: regex, perl

```
$search_buffer="this text has teststring in it, it has a Test String too";
@waitfor=('Test string','some other string');

foreach my $test (@waitfor)
        {
            eval ('if (lc $search_buffer =~ lc ' . $test . ') ' .
                  '{' .
                  '    $prematch = $`;' .
                  '    $match = $&; ' .
                  '    $postmatch = ' . "\$';" .
                  '}');

            print "prematch=$prematch\n";
            print "match=$match\n"; #I want to match both "teststring" and "Test String"
            print "postmatch=$postmatch\n";
        }
```

I need to print both teststring and Test String, can you please help? thanks.

Comment: Why are you using [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)? This code would work nearly the same way outside of the `eval`. The main difference being the `eval` version is slower, and has a potential security exploit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $search_buffer="this text has teststring in it, it has a Test String too";

my $pattern = qr/test ?string/i;

say "Match found: $1" while $search_buffer =~ /($pattern)/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a horrible piece of code you have there. Why are you using `eval` and trying to concatenate strings into code, remembering to interpolate some variables and forgetting about some? There is no reason to use `eval` in that situation at all.

I assume that you by using `lc` are trying to make the match case-insensitive. This is best done by using the `/i` modifier on your regex:

```
$search_buffer =~ /$test/i;   # case insensitive match
```

In your case, you are trying to match some strings against another string, and you want to compensate for case and for possible whitespace inside. I assume that your strings are generated in some way, and not hard coded.

What you could do is simply to make use of the `/x` modifier, which will make literal whitespace inside your regex ignored.

Something that you should take into consideration is meta characters inside your strings. If you for example have a string such as `foo?`, the meta character `?` will alter the meaning of your regex. You can disable meta characters inside a regex with the `\Q ... \E` escape sequence.

So the solution is

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $s = "this text has teststring in it, it has a Test String too";
my @waitfor= ('Test string','some other string', '#test string');

for my $str (@waitfor) {
    if ($s =~ /\Q$str/xi) {
        say "prematch  = $`";
        say "match     = $&";
        say "postmatch = $'";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
prematch  = this text has teststring in it, it has a
match     = Test String
postmatch =  too
```

Note that I use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

These two pragmas are vital to learning how to write good Perl code, and there is no (valid) reason you should ever write code without them.

Answer (score 1):

This would work for your specific example.

```
test\s?string
```

Basically it marks the space as optional `[\s]?`.
The problem that I'm seeing with this is that it requires you to know where exactly there might be a space inside the string you're searching.

**Note:** You might also have to use the case-insensitive flag which would be `/Test[\s]?String/i`

Comment: sequence \s is not space char, but character class for non visible characters that takes single cell. it is called white character. for example it matches space and tab together, and some other characters.